# Prove that the only continuously differentiable functions of one variable satisfying the mean value property are lines.

Tags: real-analysis

Define a function $f$ to have the mean value property if $f(\frac{s+t}{2}) = \frac{f(s)}{2} + \frac{f(t)}{2}$ for all $s$ and $t$ in $\mathbb{R}$. I'm trying to show that if $f$ is continuously differentiable and has the mean value property then it is of the form $f(x) = ax + b$. Using the limit of the difference quotient I was able to show that $2f'(x) - f'(2x) = f'(0)$ but this doesn't show that the derivative is constant as if $f'(x) = x$ then this equation would also be satisfied. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiating the equation with respect to $t$ gives you $\frac{1}{2}f'\left(\frac{s+t}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2} f'(t)$, or $f'\left(\frac{s+t}{2}\right) = f'(t)$. On the other hand, differentiating with respect to $s$  gives $f'\left(\frac{s+t}{2}\right) = f'(s)$. Hence $f'(s)=f'(t)$. Since $s,t$ are arbitrary, we conclude $f'$ is constant.

Comment: Thanks. As usuali I made this problem harder than it should be